# What do the parameter in sha3() in Proof of Work implementation of Ethereum mean

Tags: proof-of-work, sha3

```
sha3(nonce, currentChallenge, block.blockhash(block.number-1))
```

In this line I get it that blockhash is a random number, but why are we taking it from the previous block, any hard and fast rule here ?

```
sha3(nonce, currentChallenge)
```

In this line there are only two parameters , is third variable a default one in implementation of sha3 ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
sha3(nonce, currentChallenge, block.blockhash(block.number-1))
```

- **nonce** is a unique increasing by one value that ensures that the transaction is unique and not a replay of a previous transaction
- **currentChallenge** a uniformly random value that is used in the [PoW](https://github.com/ethereum/wiki/wiki/Mining); for the exact details see page 6 of the [yellow paper](http://gavwood.com/paper.pdf)
- **block.blockhash(block.number-1)** a hash that has the role of a pointer to the previous block in the block chain. This is the chaining mechanism that holds the block chain together

Answer (score 1):

Is sha3 you can pass any number of parameters. It will return a hash of the conatenated string.

Previous block is required to verify the parent of the block.

Comment: Thanks, No of arguments is clear. But I'm unable to understand that why do we need to verify the parent , why the immediate parent why not block.number-2 ?